# Solr Optimizing results for existing customers

Tags: java, search, solr

Given a set of about 500 users who use the newly created search system.
On every search on back end I have log(mysql) for the term searched with facets applied on the facet field as well as user ID.

How do I boost the results for the users whose search is already known to me. E.g. 
if user searches for a specific term every time, how do I put it at the top as soon as the user arrives on the search part of the site.
How do I boost results based on the previous search terms.

P.S sorry for nooby question, just starting with Solr.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Are you looking for some king for something like typeahead (google like) suggester or only interested in just boosting the search results alone? because i see you mentioned "I put it at the top as soon as the user arrives on the search part " which makes me believe this is for type ahead or auto complete kind of scenario. Please confirm

Comment: "boost results based on the previous search terms" note that there may very different searches that user might have provided for example iphone and TV. boosting TV when the user types in iphone may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are talking, right UI component, right terms retrieving component and also how personalization of terms

1. UI Rendering and Personalization: The jquery autocomplete component or similar UI library can be used to add the user specific results (terms) independently along with general search results (from solr). Use Javascript array based implementation to add the results.
2. For Search we have multiple options Using [Suggester](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) or [Query elevation component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component). Suggester is best suited if it is more of term suggestion than search results itself. Once the search results are obtained, include the user specific terms into jquery/JS component by adding personal results from the server.

Query elevation is typically user agnostic and are terms dependent, but elevation xml can be customized to add a user specific terms for each query so that appropriate documents are added. This option may not fit your use case well given that this is really designed for user specific searches and may involve constant/periodic updates to this xml.